# NullPointerException error in my ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a fragment which I want to display a `ListView`

here's a portion of my code

```
public class ExpensesDaily extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lvExpenses = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Cursor expensesListCursor;
        DbControl dbc = new DbControl(getActivity());
        try {
            dbc.open();
            expensesListCursor = dbc.listExpenses();
            String[] from = new String[] {"description", "cost" };
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_expenses, expensesListCursor, from, new int[] { R.id.tvDescription, R.id.tvCost },0);
            lvExpenses.setAdapter(adapter);
        }catch (SQLException e){

        }
    dbc.close();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState)    {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses_daily, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

** DbControl class**

```
public class DbControl {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MySQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    public DbControl(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);

}

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public Cursor listExpenses(){
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES, new String[] {"id _id", "description, cost"}, "forDate='" + date + "'", null, null, null, "id asc");


    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

**expenses_daily.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll_expensesDaily"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_expenses.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="7dip">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:id="@+id/tvCost" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but everytime I load the fragment, it will display this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at com.code.imin.mymoneymanaged.ExpensesDaily.onCreate(ExpensesDaily.java:60)
```

which points to the line

```
lvExpenses.setAdapter(adapter) in class ExpensesDaily.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lvExpenses = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);`

You can't call `getActivity().findViewById` on onCreate because the view was not created yet. Change that logic to onActivityCreated

[image]

Comment: You want to call your View declarations in onCreateView() (using rootView.findViewById(...)) or save rootView as a class-wide variable and declare them in onActivityCreated().

Comment: `getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list)` can be safely called on `onActivityCreated` and it will return the view just fine. No need to save the "rootView" as a field.

Comment: @PedroOliveira not sure why but it seems I need to use rootView.findViewById(...) and can't just use getActivity().findViewById() because that will make my app crash with null pointer